# How can I test if nginx configuration files are valid within a Bash script?

Tags: scripting, configuration, nginx

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Bash version 4.4.0
- nginx version: nginx/1.14.0

How can I test the Nginx configuration files in a Bash script? At the moment I use -t when I'm in a shell:

```
$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

But I would like to do this in a script?

Comment: Put the command into the script just like you would any other command.

Comment: what do you want the shell script to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the exit status. From the nginx manpage:

> Exit status is 0 on success, or 1 if the command fails.

and from http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html:

> $? reads the exit status of the last command executed.

An example:

```
[root@d ~]# /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -t;echo $?
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test is     successful
0
[root@d ~]# echo whatever > /usr/local/nginx/nonsense.conf
[root@d ~]# /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -t -c nonsense.conf;echo $?
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /usr/local/nginx/nonsense.conf:2
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/nginx/nonsense.conf test failed
1
```

A scripted example:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -t 2>/dev/null > /dev/null
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
 echo "success"
 # do things on success
else
 echo "fail"
 # do whatever on fail
fi
```

Comment: In the script, you can do just `if nginx -t 2>/dev/null; then ...; else ...; fi` instead of testing on `$?`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I know, I just thought my way would better explain what's going on

Comment: @DeeEff I like the explanation and it makes sense. I was trying to compare the entire output of `nginx -t`.  I learned a lot from this. Hats off to you mate.

Answer (score -1):

@DeeEff Above bash script whether that will work nginx container to cloud vm or cloud vm to nginx container

Example sudo containername  -t

bash program/script that can check the Nginx service. The script or program should print "OK" and exit with code 0 if the
"Hello World" page is returned. If the "Hello World" page is not returned it should exit with
a non-zero code and a short diagnostic.

Comment: It is unclear whether this is an answer or a comment to another solution; if it is an answer, then please address the question.